# Map<dynamic,dynamic> is null after loading currencies from API

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate

Any idea why my currencies map is null in the CurrencyConverterState class? I am loading currencies from an API to my currencies map in class API (see code for class API) and also trying to set state after the loading is done. After loading the currencies from the API to my currencies map I can also access the rates from the map so that means that my map is working fine and is not null. I did that test by printing a currency rate and it was fine. But that works just in the API class. The problem is that as soon as I test my currencies map in class CurrencyConverterState it says that the map is null and I am stuck in circular progress indicator (see code for class CurrencyConverterState). I dont really know why it says that the map is null. Any help appreciated.

API class code:

```
class API 
{
  var fromTextController = new TextEditingController();

  Map<dynamic, dynamic> currencies;

  String fromCurrency;
  String toCurrency;

  String result;

  API(String from, String to){
    fromCurrency = from;
    toCurrency = to;
  }

  Future<dynamic> loadCurrencies() async {
    String uri = "http://api.openrates.io/latest";
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(uri), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    Map curMap = responseBody['rates'];
    currencies = curMap;
    setState(() {});
    print (currencies["SEK"]);
  }


  Future<dynamic> doConversion() async {
    String uri =
        "http://api.openrates.io/latest?base=$fromCurrency&symbols=$toCurrency";
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(uri), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    setState(() {
      result = (double.parse(fromTextController.text) *
          (responseBody["rates"][toCurrency]))
          .toString();
    });
    setState(() {});
    return "Success";
  }

  void setState(Null Function() param0) {}
}
```

CurrencyConverterState class code:

```
class CurrencyConverterState extends State<CurrencyConverter> {
  final API api = new API("USD", "SEK");

  CurrencyConverterState();

  int i = 1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
     api.loadCurrencies();
    api.fromTextController.addListener(doConversion);
    setState(() {

    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        body: api.currencies?.keys == null
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : Stack(children: [
                Positioned(
                  top: 30,
                  child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Card(
                          elevation: 10,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                'Converter',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black, fontSize: 22.0),
                              ),
                              ListTile(
                                title: TextField(
                                  controller: api.fromTextController,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                      hintText: 'Enter a number'),
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black),
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.numberWithOptions(
                                      decimal: true),
                                ),
                                trailing:
                                    buildDropDownButton(api.fromCurrency),
                              ),
                              ListTile(
                                title: Chip(
                                    label: api.result != null
                                        ? Container(
                                            width: 1000,
                                            height: 40,
                                            child: Text(
                                              api.result,
                                              style: Theme.of(context)
                                                  .textTheme
                                                  .headline4,
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        : Container(
                                            width: 1000,
                                            height: 40,
                                            child: Text(" "))),
                                trailing:
                                    buildDropDownButton(api.toCurrency),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]));
  }

  Widget buildDropDownButton(String currencyCategory) {
    return DropdownButton(
        value: currencyCategory,
        dropdownColor: Colors.white,
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
        iconSize: 24,
        items: api.currencies.keys.map((dynamic value) => DropdownMenuItem(
                value: value,
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                  Text(value),
                ])))
            .toList(),
        onChanged: (dynamic value) {
          if (currencyCategory == api.fromCurrency) {
            api.fromCurrency = value;
          } else {
            api.toCurrency = value;
          }
          setState(() {});
        });
  }

  doConversion() {
    api.doConversion();
    setState(() {});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are retrieving currencies before they get retrieved and you are never updating the UIs when they are retrieved.

This is a possible solution:

```
//In API class
Future<Map<String,dynamic>> loadCurrencies() async {
    String uri = "http://api.openrates.io/latest";
    var response = await http
        .get(Uri.encodeFull(uri), headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
    var responseBody = json.decode(response.body);
    Map<String,dynamic> curMap = responseBody['rates'];
    print (currencies["SEK"]);
    return curMap;
}
```

Then in your main class use a futureBuilder:

```
return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
        body: FutureBuilder(
           future: api.loadCurrencies(),
           builder: (context, currencies) =>{
             return currencies==null?
             ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
             : Stack(/*rest of your code*/);
        })
);
```

Comment: Remember to vote for positive answers, this will help future readers to understand what to do if they are stuck

Comment: I did but because I am new and have below 15 reputation it wont show.